# Consuming webservice using Jquerymobile, Ajax and PHP (Login)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, web-services, jquery-mobile

I have created a database on Jelastic with mySQL and Jelastic does not allow php pages be hosted on there, so I have created a web service to help me. I currently have my login.php hosted locally. The web service has a function called, getCustomQuery, but I'm trying a different approach at the moment to hopefully bypass using the web service.

Okay so this is my index.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Submit a form via AJAX</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js">     <script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
       function onSuccess(data, status)
       {
           data = $.trim(data);
           $("#notification").text(data + " Success");
       }

       function onError(data, status)
       {
           $("#notification").text(data+ " " + status);
       }        

       $(document).ready(function() {
           $("#submit").click(function(){

               var formData = $("#callAjaxForm").serialize();

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "login.php",
                   cache: false,
                   dataType: "text",
                   data: formData,
                   success: onSuccess,
                   error: onError
               });

               return false;
           });
       });
   </script>

   <!-- call ajax page -->
   <div data-role="page" id="callAjaxPage">
       <div data-role="header">
           <h1>Call Ajax</h1>
       </div>

       <div data-role="content">
           <form id="callAjaxForm">
               <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                   <label for="userName">Username</label>
                   <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value=""  />

                   <label for="passWord">Password</label>
                   <input type="text" name="passWord" id="passWord" value=""  />
                   <h3 id="notification"> Something here</h3>
                   <button data-theme="b" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
               </div>
           </form>
       </div>


   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the index page gets a username and password and posts it to teh login page, using jquery and ajax.

```
<?php

$userName = $_POST[userName];
$passWord = $_POST[passWord];

echo("LastName: " . $userName . " Password: " . $passWord);

$con = mysql_connect("url", "username", "password"); 
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$passWordMD5 = md5($passWord , false);
mysql_select_db("club_in", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_username='+ $userName+' AND user_password='+$passWordMD5+'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['user_username'] . " " . $row['user_password'];
    echo "<br />";
}


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Now the login.php page gets the two variables passed to it from the index.html page. The login.php md5 hashes the password, because all passwords are stored as md5 hashes to help a bit with security, if the database gets hacked. 
Now this is where things get a little fuzzy for me, since I've tried the SQL query and it works in mySQL and when it returns to the index.html page I get a success, but the only thing that I get back is a the whole text of the php page. 
I only need the info that the login.php page was suppose to pull from the database. Would you please help? Any useful suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you get the php code instead of the parsed result:

- the webserver doesn't know php. do you have a php parser installed?
- the webserver cannot execute the script. what are the file persmissions? (linux)

Comment: I'm currently using Xampp and mySQL on my PC to host the php page and it has used php before. But are you asking if the web server on Jelastic can understand php? I don't think so.

But I have tried using a function called getCustomQuery which I made on the webserver that takes in a string but I just get as many errors. I'm trying to see if there is any way of working with this before I have to change everything.

And I'm using windows.

Comment: so your index.html and login.php are both hosted locally? does it work there?